# How do I get gnome-terminal not to truncate lines?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have a huge xml file which I want to look at with `cat some.xml | less` but the gnome terminal truncates the lines making it difficult to read the output.

How do I get gnome-terminal not to truncate lines? Or, Is there a better way to scroll through files too big to fit in memory?

Comment: Could you elaborate or add a screenshot? I just looked at an XML file with very long lines in the terminal and they don't get truncated, they wrap like they should. BTW, unnecessary use of cat. less takes a filename as parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mem75 already said, gnome-terminal doesn't truncate, but wrap long lines. But you're using `less` anyway, in which case it's that which is doing the wrapping.

To tell `less` not to wrap long lines, use the `--chop-long-lines` (or `-S` for short) option. (They're only chopped as far as the display is concerned, and you can scroll left and right with the arrow keys.)